# Figures and text side by side

Tags: floats, subfloats, two-column, minipage

I'm struggling to put a series of five graphics side by side with the normal text. The figures are put as `subfloat` and placed inside a common `figure` environment to be able to give them a common `caption`.

I tried `minipages` so far, but they don't align side by side (old `minipage` problem), because one of them is inside the `figure` environment to be able to use `subfloat`. `multicol` seemed to be a solution, but didn't help at all.

Some ideas how to get the job done?

MnWE as follows:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hbt]
 \begin{minipage}[h]{0.28\textwidth}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{format=plain}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{somegraphics}}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{somegraphics}}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{somegraphics}}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{somegraphics}}
    \caption{some fancy caption}
 \end{minipage}%
\end{figure}%
 \begin{minipage}
  some text... \lorem
 \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
The `wrapfigure` solution from Gonzalo worked well for me, but as the figures should span the whole page on the left side, you have to be careful not to make the `wrapfigure` environment too large.
It easily extends to the next page without you even noticing it (because the visible part stays on one page). Try to set the height of the individual figures, so the whole environment fits one page.

Comment: The second `minipage` is missing the mandatory argument (the width).

Comment: How should the five subfigures be arranged?

Comment: I mean the problem with minipages not being displayed side by side, unless you put a `%` right after the other, so the first one is followed directly by the second one.
The `figure` environment suppressed that and I didn't come up with another solution than `minipage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description of the problem suggests that you want text to wrap around the subfigure arrangement; in this case, the `wrapfigure` environment from the [`wrapfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) package could be used; in comments it was mentioned that the subfigures should appear one below the other:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.28\textwidth}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{format=plain}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}\par
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}\par
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}\par
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}\par
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}
    \caption{some fancy caption}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since you are loading the caption package, you could as well use the [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package instead of `subfig` and its `subfigure` enviornment or its `\subcaptionbox` command; an example using the latter:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.28\textwidth}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{format=plain}
    \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}\par
    \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}\par
    \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}\par
    \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}\par
    \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}
    \caption{some fancy caption}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: okay, that does look not too far away from what I actually want!
I will give the `wrapfigure` approach a try.
The figures should be arranged one below another...

Comment: @Knigge46 Perhaps if you had explained from the beginning what you actually want, I could've helped to get there more efficiently .). Do you wnat the text to wrap around the figure arrangement?

Comment: @Knigge46 Please see my updated answer.

Comment: thank you so far, that does work for me. The arrangement of the figures doesn't play such a big role, I think...
Next problem is: the figure seems to stretch over to the next page (although it physically doesn't!). what causes this behaviour?

Comment: @Knigge46 there's a number of precautions to be taken into account when using `wrapfigure` (most importantly, not to use it near a page break); please refer to the package documentation to see them. You can also try `\usepackage[verbose]{wrapfig}` and reviewing the console output (or the `.log` file) to look for any clues about what's happening.

Comment: aside from an underfull `vbox` nothing suspicious happens while wrapping the text...

Comment: @Knigge46 If you, who have the actual code, don't see any problems, how do you expect us to guess what's going on? Please compose a MWE reproducing the problem and add it to your question as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

I found comfy this code :

```
\begin{figure}
    \parbox[h]{6cm}{'text here'}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}
        'figure here'
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```